# Nagios only create warning for a http service

Tags: ubuntu, nagios

I would like to also monitor non-crucial services with nagios like for example our GitLab-server or phpMyAdmin instance. Is there any way to just create warnings instead of critical errors for some services?

At the moment I'm using the following:

```
define service {
    host_name localhost
    use generic-service
    service_description HTTP GitLab
    check_command check_www!git.example.com!'/users/sign_in'
}

define command {
    command_name check_www
    command_line /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -H '$ARG1$' -I '$HOSTADDRESS$' -e 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' -u '$ARG2$'
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [negate plugin](https://www.nagios-plugins.org/doc/man/negate.html) exists for exactly this reason.

Using the -c option, you can change CRITICAL to WARNING. For example, you could do this:

```
define command {
    command_name check_www_no_crit
    command_line /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/negate -s -c WARNING /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -H '$ARG1$' -I '$HOSTADDRESS$' -e 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' -u '$ARG2$'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that you're using `check_http` with the `-e` flag, to check a return code.  That plugin doesn't seem to offer the option of returning a WARNING (rather than a CRITICAL) error if the `-e` check fails.

You would need to write a small shell script wrapper around `check_http` that passed the output through unchanged, but checked the return code of the plugin, did an `exit 1` if the plugin's return code was 2, and passed the return code through unchanged otherwise.